# Twilio Pass conference name using session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

Hi guys I am having a problem with twilio currently setting an assignment to a worker and i need to pass the worker to the conference. My problem is that i cant use session to retrieve the id in the session and the id will be the conference name of the conference to be able to have a unique conference name for a worker.

This is my callback in twilio
[image]
This is my code to get the task. And the id will be passed on forward_queue_conference.

```
public function assignment()
{ 
    id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 
    $TaskAttributes = $_POST['TaskAttributes'];
    $json = json_decode($TaskAttributes, true);   
    $this->Mytwilio->SetAssignment($json['from'], AFTERTALK, HTTP_BASE_URL."agent/call_controls/forward_queue_conference?data=".$id);
}
```

This is my code on forward_queue_conference to retrieve the pass data

```
public function forward_queue_conference()
{     
    roomName = $_GET['data'];
    $this->Mytwilio->CallerToQueue($roomName);
}
```

MyTwilio is a library that i made for twilio functions.

```
function CallerToQueue($roomName)
{
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $dial = $response->dial();
    $dial->conference($roomName, array(
        'startConferenceOnEnter' => 'true',
        'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true',
        'muted' => 'false',
        'record' => 'record-from-start',
        'waitUrl' => 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient',
    ));

    print $response;
}
```

And this is my whole process my problem is that i cant get the session data to become the conference room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio makes a callback to a URL on your website, it does not share the same session as your logged in user. It is therefore impossible to get the current user ID from the session.

However, your workers have an ID in the Twilio system. And that ID is sent as part of [the parameters for the webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#assignment-callback-parameters). So, I recommend using the `WorkerSid` as the conference room instead of your own ID. Or alternatively, you could map between your worker ID and the user ID in your system.

Comment: Oh ty so much this is a good idea but how can i call workersid?

Comment: When you create a worker using the REST API you will get their SID, when the webhook comes in, the SID will be in the parameters of the request.